# Changing property causes detail view to pop back to list view

Tags: swiftui

I have a list view created from core data, and it's sectioned by a property called favourite. In the detail view a user is able to either add an item or remove it as a favourite.

When the property is updated, it causes the detail view to pop back to the list view, which I don't want it to do, and don't know how to get it to not do that

The creation of the list

```swift
    @SectionedFetchRequest var dims: SectionedFetchResults<Int16, DIM>

    init() {
        _dims = SectionedFetchRequest<Int16, DIM>(
            sectionIdentifier: \.favourite,
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DIM.favourite, ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DIM.name, ascending: true)]
        )
    }

    List {
        ForEach(dims) { section in
            let header: String = nameForSectionHeader(sectionID: section.id)
            Section(header: Text(header)) {
                ForEach(section) { dim in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DIMListView(dim: dim)) {
                                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then on the detail view there's a toolbar with an option to add/remove favourite.

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button("Options") {
            showingAlertFav = true
        }
        .alert("Choose an option", isPresented: $showingAlertFav) {
            if dim.favourite == 0 {
                Button("Favourite", role: .none) {
                    setFav(fav: 1)
                }
            } else {
                Button("Unfavourite", role: .none) {
                    setFav(fav: 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


func setFav(fav : Int16) {
    dim.favourite = fav
    saveContext()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by making the core data save on when going back to the previous view rather than straight away

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you have done?
I added CloudKit support to my app and switched from `struct` to `class` models. Now I am facing this issue. After pushing a DetailView from a ListView, the DetailView instantaneously pops back to the ListView.

Comment: Can fix it now using NavigationStack rather than view. But what I did initially was save core data straight away, now I save when I press back

Comment: Sounds like another problem on my side. I don't have changes and I don't save the context at all in this situation. But Thank you for your response.

Comment: NavigationStack(path: …) was my problem on mac-catalyst. Now I'm using NavigationStack without path ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationStack to instead of it.

#Only iOS 16.0+

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).